# iPhoneのカメラ設定のDestinationType.NATIVE_URIだとcorrectOrientation:trueが反映されない

Tags: ios, monaca, camera

機種名:iPhone5
Cordova:ver4.1
OSのver:8.13

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(setPicture, failCamera, {
                quality: 25,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
                correctOrientation: true,   
                sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
});
```

表題の通り、`Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI`だと`correctOrientation: true`が反映されず、アルバムから選択した写真が全て横になってしまいます。
尚、`destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`にすれば、写真の向きがしっかり反映されるのですが写真の緯度経度が消えてしまうため、現状では使用することが出来ません。

何かいい解決策等あればご教授ください。

Comment: すいません。私の勘違いでした。
しっかりと機能致します。